# Newtonian interpretation of the Friedman-equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, cosmology

I'm a first year physics student so I cannot yet understand general relativity, yet the Friedman-Lemaître-Robertson-Walker (What's in a name?) equations are used in my introductory course in astronomy, and I'm trying to understand them as best as I can.

I have watched some of Leonard Susskinds video's on Cosmology which are available on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=938_TNP4aUs&t=1923s) where he derives the FLRW equation. He does so in a Newtonian way - which is the same way how it is done in my course book. The equation I'm talking about is:

$$ \dfrac{\dot{a}^2}{a^2}=\dfrac{8\pi G}{3}\rho-\dfrac{kc^2}{a^2},$$

and since this is in conventional notation, I suppose whoever reads this is familiar with the variables.

My question is if my interpretation is correct. I interpret each term as an energy term: the first (left side) being a kinetic term, the second (first right) a potential (negative) and the last one being proportional to the total energy content of the universe. This way it's als easier to see why different values of $k$ result in different kinds of universes.

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct, in a classical sense.  Both FLRW equations can be found from Newtonian mechanics, using Newton's equation (for $\ddot{a}$) and conservation of energy (for $\dot{a}^2$), but it's working only without taking pressure into account (which is a relativistic feature).  This is a well known thing.  Just use $F = m \, \frac{d^2 \, x}{dt^2}$ and $E = \frac{1}{2} \, m \, \dot{x}^2 + U$, and $F = -\, \frac{G M m}{r^2} - \kappa \, x$ and $U =-\, \frac{G M m}{r} + \frac{1}{2} \, \kappa x^2$.  It's really easy, just a few changes of notation in variables.

Comment: Please don't add 'answered' to titles, there is already a system in place to notify users of an answered question.